# Python variables change in every object

Tags: python, pygame

I'm playing around with pygame for the first time, trying to make multiple rectangles move across the screen. Here's my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

scrWidth = 1200
scrHeigth = 900
done = False
rectangles = []

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scrWidth, scrHeigth))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Rectangle:
    speed = [1,1]
    colourSpeed = 300
    colourID = 0
    colour = (0, 0, 255)
    size = 60

    def __init__(self, name = "", x=0, y=0, speed=False, colour=False, size=False):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.doesSpeed = speed
        self.doesColour = colour
        self.doesSize = size

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size))

    def checkCollision(self):
        if self.x < 0 or self.x > scrWidth-self.size:
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
        if self.y < 0 or self.y > scrHeigth-self.size:
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.speed[0]
        self.y += self.speed[1]

    def changeColour(self):
        self.colourID = (self.colourID+1)%self.colourSpeed
        if 0 <= self.colourID < (self.colourSpeed/3):
            self.colour = (0, 0, 255)
        elif (self.colourSpeed/3) <= self.colourID < (2*self.colourSpeed/3):
            self.colour = (0, 255, 0)
        elif (2*self.colourSpeed/3) <= self.colourID < self.colourSpeed:
            self.colour = (255, 0, 0)




rect1 = Rectangle("rect1", 30, 30, False, True, False)
rectangles.append(rect1)
rect2 = Rectangle("rect2", 300, 300)
rectangles.append(rect2)


while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for obj in rectangles:
        obj.checkCollision()
        if obj.doesColour: obj.changeColour()
        obj.move()
        obj.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

The problem is that when a rectangle collides with the edge of the screen all rectangles change direction(speed). However if I make rectangles with different speeds this doesn't happen.

ex: rect1 has speed [1,1] and rect2 has speed [2,2].

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know why you have a class variable for `speed`, but I would recommend you to get rid of it. You need to also adjust it in every method...

Comment: `speed` is a class attribute, mutable value shared across all instances. You have to create individual list in each instance `__init__` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the speed, colourSpeed, colourID, colour, size to the **init** method.

At that moment that fields are defined as class fields, so they are changed globally for all rectangles.

**Solution**:

```
def __init__(self, name = "", x=0, y=0, speed=False, colour=False, size=False):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.doesSpeed = speed
        self.doesColour = colour
        self.doesSize = size
        # here it comes
        self.speed = [1,1]
        self.colourSpeed = 300
        self.colourID = 0
        self.colour = (0, 0, 255)
        self.size = 60
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. How come it did work when I changed the speed to an absolute value? (rect1.speed = [2,2])

Comment: @SJ_WTF I would like to see your code now, because with this solution really nothing changes

Comment: @LPK yeah answered before the code block showed up in this answer for me. You should have self.speed etc inside the init

Comment: Sorry, I just copied lines straight to initializator. Now it should work.